# Borrar dato de una tabla conectada a BD con Java

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing, crud

El día de hoy recurro a uds con el fin de pedirles su ayuda para el siguiente problema. Resultado que tengo una tabla en JAVA que esta conectada a una BD(Mysql). Quiero eliminar un registro de est tabla pero al intentarlo me marca el siguiento error "**incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int**".

A continuación el código del metodo eliminar

```
public boolean eliminarEmpleado(int cedula) {
    boolean resultado = false;

    try {
        String sql = "Delete from tercero where id = "+cedula;
        objConec.conectar();
        Statement st = objConec.conex.createStatement();
        int valor = st.executeUpdate(sql);
        if(valor>0){
            resultado = true;
        }
        objConec.conex.close();
        st.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al eliminar" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

A continuació el código de mi botón de eliminar

```
private void btnEliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    empleado objEmpleado = new empleado();

    //Asigno el modelo para el JTable
    DefaultTableModel modeloTabla = (DefaultTableModel) tblEmpleado.getModel();

    //Asigno el indice del elemento seleccionado
    int indice = tblEmpleado.getSelectedRow();

    //Asigno al campo cedula el elemto a eliminar
    //int cedula = Integer.parseInt((String)modeloTabla.getValueAt(indice,0));
    int cedula = (int) modeloTabla.getValueAt(indice, 0);

    //Elimino el registro de la tabla
    modeloTabla.removeRow(indice);

    //Elimino el registro
    boolean respuesta = objEmpleado.eliminarEmpleado("delete from empleado where cedula = '"+cedula+"' ");
}
```

El error me lo marca en está línea

```
boolean respuesta = objEmpleado.eliminarEmpleado("delete from empleado where cedula = '"+cedula+"' ");
```

Comment: Tu método `eliminarEmpleado` acepta un parámetro de tipo *int*, no *String*. Tienes que pasarle solo el valor de `cédula`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo encarecidamente que cuando tengas que realizar concadenaciones en consultas de ese tipo uses prepared statement, puesto que esas concadenaciones son suceptibles a SQL Inyection. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo de como sería la consulta, en vez de usar un objeto statement se usa uno llamado preparedStatement:

```
public void eliminarEmpleado(int cedula){

 String consulta= "delete from empleado where cedula = ?";
 preparedStatement = conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
 preparedStatement .setInt(1, cedula);
 preparedStatement .executeUpdate();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que menciona **Sjuan76** es correcto, amigo tu método *eliminarEmpleado* recibe el valor del atributo "*cedula*" solamente y sin embargo cuando lo llamas en el botón le estas enviado la query completa al método... en fin solo debes enviar el valor de *cedula* debido a que la query y conexión a BD lo tienes programado en el método que mencioné al principio.
saludos.

Comment: Por favor, no uses las respuestas para escribir comentarios. Y si esto es un intento de respuesta, intenta añadir más detalles (¿cómo se aplicaría lo que sugieres al código de la pregunta?) para que sea de más ayuda al usuario que pregunta o a otros usuarios que puedan encontrarse con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias,ya lo resulví siguiendo sus recomendaciones. Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera: en lugar de devolver la query completa solo envíe el dato 'cedula'.

```
private void btnEliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    empleado objEmpleado = new empleado();

    //Asigno el modelo para el JTable
    DefaultTableModel modeloTabla = (DefaultTableModel) tblEmpleado.getModel();

    //Asigno el indice del elemento seleccionado
    int indice = tblEmpleado.getSelectedRow();

    //Asigno al campo cedula el elemto a eliminar
    //int cedula = Integer.parseInt((String)modeloTabla.getValueAt(indice,0));
    int cedula = (int) modeloTabla.getValueAt(indice, 0);   

    //Elimino el registro de la tabla
    modeloTabla.removeRow(indice);

    //Elimino el registro
    objEmpleado.eliminarEmpleado(cedula);          
}
```

Sin embargo, me queda un pequeña pregunta con respecto a lo que me dijo **SJuan76** de las SQL Inyection. 
   public boolean eliminarEmpleado(int cedula) {
        /*
        String consulta = "delete from empleado where cedula = ?";
        preparedStatement = conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
        preparedStatement .setInt(1, cedula);
        preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
        */

```
    boolean resultado = false;

    try {
        String sql = "Delete from empleado where cedula = ?";
        objConec.conectar();
        PreparedStatement ps = conectar.PrepareStatement(sql);
        PreparedStatement .setInt(1, cedula);
        PreparedStatement .executeUpdate(1);
        if(valor>0){
            resultado = true;
        }
        objConec.conex.close();
        st.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al eliminar" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return resultado;

}
```

Intente hacerlo coo tu me dijiste, pero me marcaba bastantes errores. El mayor error que tengo es que no se como asignarle la variable conexion para que luego se use dentro del preparedStatement.

Muchas gracias de nuevo!